# Using a button to increment a for loop in a GUI

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

A friend and I are making a GUI based maths game for a university project. We are stuck at one specific point. We have two equations showing on screen, and the user can select whether the first equation is smaller, larger or equal to the second equation. We want this to happen 10 times. So whenever the user selects one of the 3 options, the next two equations must show. On the first iteration, the two equations show and you can select an answer. When this is done though, the equations stay the same, and you can indefinitely click any of the 3 buttons without the equations changing or the loop ending after 10 button presses. There are three different games to select, which is selected in the first statement. These two statements run in the main GUI method (where all the buttons are declared and created):

```
calcEquations();
gameCount++;
```

These happen in the button handlers and an extra method to calculate the two equations.

```
private class ButtonHandler extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == backButton)
        {
            gameScreenFrame.dispose();
            GameSelectGUI gameSelectGUI = new GameSelectGUI();
            gameSelectGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            gameSelectGUI.setSize(gameScreenFrame.getSize());
            gameSelectGUI.setLocation(gameScreenFrame.getLocation());
            gameSelectGUI.setVisible(true);
        }

        while(gameCount < 10)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == smallButton)
            {
                // gameScreenFrame.dispose();
                // ResultsGUI resultsGUI = new ResultsGUI();
                // resultsGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // resultsGUI.setSize(gameScreenFrame.getSize());
                // resultsGUI.setLocation(gameScreenFrame.getLocation());
                // resultsGUI.setVisible(true);
                calcEquations();
                gameCount++;

                if(eq1 < eq2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Smaller Correct");
                }
            }

            if(event.getSource() == equalButton)
            {
                // gameScreenFrame.dispose();
                // ResultsGUI resultsGUI = new ResultsGUI();
                // resultsGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // resultsGUI.setSize(gameScreenFrame.getSize());
                // resultsGUI.setLocation(gameScreenFrame.getLocation());
                // resultsGUI.setVisible(true);

                calcEquations();
                gameCount++;

                if(eq1 == eq2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Equal Correct");
                }
            }

            if(event.getSource() == largeButton)
            {
                // gameScreenFrame.dispose();
                // ResultsGUI resultsGUI = new ResultsGUI();
                // resultsGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                // resultsGUI.setSize(gameScreenFrame.getSize());
                // resultsGUI.setLocation(gameScreenFrame.getLocation());
                // resultsGUI.setVisible(true);

                calcEquations();                    
                gameCount++;

                if(eq1 > eq2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Larger Correct");
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}

public void calcEquations()
{
    if(game == 'A')
    {
        AccuracyGame objGame = new AccuracyGame(gameLvl, gameType);
        eq1 = objGame.Equation();
        eq1Str = objGame.toString();
        eq2 = objGame.Equation();
        eq2Str = objGame.toString();
        eqOneLabel.setText(eq1Str);
        eqTwoLabel.setText(eq2Str);
    }
}
```

It allows you to answer once, and then it shows a new set of equations, but at this point none of the 3 buttons work. We added an output in the buttons to display in console what happens, and it shows that pressing the button once answers all 10 question at once. Is there a way to stop the program from running all 10 at once, and allowing us to click once to answer each set of equations?

Comment: Your loop is inside the handler for the action, so it will finish after a single button press. Take the loop out of the action handler. You just want to increment `gameCount` but you don't want to loop.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `calcEquations` method is called from a while loop until the `gameCount` is 10. Remove the while loop to call run it only once. For example:

```
...
        if(gameCount < 10)
        {
            if(event.getSource() == smallButton)
...
```